# Dragonbones displayed but wont animate in PixiJS game

Tags: javascript, animation, pixi.js, dragonbone

I am having a hard time making my animation work...
My project is a game made with PixiJS and vanilla JavaScript, and I need to animate game character via Dragonbones files.
The thing is that Dragonbones character is visible on screen and positioned as it should, but it is not animating when I call the animation name.

My code is down below, the first part of the code is about importing and loading Dragonbones files and it is working properly, the second part of the code is about calling animation.
I have tried to add "ticker", and update it via "clock", "world clock", and "FPS" but again and again nothing is happening, my character is visible on screen and not moving...
Any help is welcomed.

````
    const femaleVikingTextures = PIXI.Loader.shared;
    femaleVikingTextures
      .add("female_viking_ske", "dragonbones_assets/female_viking_ske.json")
      .add("female_viking_tex", "dragonbones_assets/female_viking_tex.json")
      .add(
        "female_viking_tex_image",
        "dragonbones_assets/female_viking_tex.png"
      )
      .load(femaleVikingSetup);

    function femaleVikingSetup() {
      dbfactory.parseDragonBonesData(
        femaleVikingTextures.resources["female_viking_ske"].data
      );
      dbfactory.parseTextureAtlasData(
        femaleVikingTextures.resources["female_viking_tex"].data,
        femaleVikingTextures.resources["female_viking_tex_image"].texture
      );

      self.armature = dbfactory.buildArmature("Armature");

      setTimeout(() => {
        self.armature.animation.play("animtion0");
        self.armature.display.anchor.set(0.45, 1);
        self.armature.display.position.set(-20, -380);
        self.armature.display.scale.x = 0.95;
        self.armature.display.scale.y = 0.95;

        self.femaleVikingContainer.addChild(self.armature.display);
      }, 1000);
    } ```
````